# AWS - Redshift Decimal issue

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am sending data from Amazon EventBridge to Redshift via an S3 Bucket.

I have an issue with decimal values that are sent.

Here is an example of my jsonpath file stored on s3.

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$.id",
        "$detail.TotalPaid"
   ] 
}
```

The column type on redshift is Decimal(12,2)

Data is saved correctly if I run an SQL insert -

```
insert into payments values(1, 10.15);
```

However if the same information is passed from EventBus then the TotalPaid column is saved as 10.14.

The above only seems to be an issue when sending a value with 2 decimal places.  If 10.1, for example, is sent then data in the column is saved correctly as 10.10

I had tried setting the column to a VARCHAR type previously but an incorrect value was saved in the database.  I was going to try using a Float type instead but looking at the AWS documentation it does say to use a DECIMAL for monetary amounts instead of floating-point types.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved.  I have to add the roundec conversion parameter to the copy command on the AWS delivery stream - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-roundec

Comment: I've had this same issue, and I just wanted to add that even though the Roundec option solves the problem, I still wasnt entirely satisfied as the input data still fits well within the precision and scale of the target field.
So I raised it with AWS support and its apparently a limitation of the Json parsing library

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT statement looks off.  Are you trying to insert the values 1 and 10.15 into the 2 columns of table payments?

If so you need to format it like - INSERT INTO payments VALUES(1, 10.15).

If not can you explain exactly what you are trying to do and the DDL of the table.

Comment: Sorry the sql insert in my initial question was incorrect.  I was running INSERT INTO payments VALUES(1, 10.15);   which worked as expected.  The issue is when the data is being sent from the AWS Event Bus to Redshift, the value of 10.15 is being saved in the database as 10.14 for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure that the value being sent isn't 10.145?  The value will round as it is cast to decimal

Comment: What I am trying to do is send an event from a microservice to an AWS event bus, then save the event in redshift.  I have checked the logs and the value sent to the event bus for TotalPaid is 10.15 as expected.  However sending that data from the event bus to redshift saves the value as 10.14 in the redshift table.

Comment: That could be the issue Bill, I will double check when back in work tomorrow.

Comment: Rounding vs. Truncating is a common issue.  BTW it is common practice for financial data to be stored as DECIMAL(19,4) to keep rounding well below the penny level and be GAAP compliant.  Then cast results to 2 significant digits when reporting out.